# Is node.js too much for a magazine/news website

Tags: node.js, content-management-system

I know node.js can build web apps that run super fast, but I just can't find enough info about how it would perform in a magazine or news style website. I know some CMS's like Joomla or Drupal (or even wordpress) are very good at it, but as the number of users grow, I'm seeing some performance issues. Naturally, the web server count but as I want to host it in the cloud, I guess working with node and just create a simple CMS based on it would suit the needs for a better user experience once many users can log in and do their social stuff parallel to the main side of the site that is just a news and reviews site. Does any node.js coder knows about it?

Comment: http://siliconangle.com/blog/2012/02/03/5-content-management-or-blog-publishing-systems-written-in-node-js/

Second result in google

Comment: I've read this...not really answer my questions. but thanks anyway @NickMitchinson

Comment: With Express or similar frameworks you can write just about any web app. It might be better to optimise your existing solution before re-writing in a new language. Are you caching?

Comment: Okay, well I may not be the best person to answer this, but if you're basically just looking for a CMS (which I think you seem to be?) it's more dependent on the one you choose than the language. Your performance is more dependent on the architecture and machines you're running on than the language you chose as well.

My point being that the language is probably the last thing you should think about. If you have a site already, you should probably look at optimising that (whether it be rearchitecting, improving what you cache, etc) than rewriting in a different language.

Comment: thanks again @NickMitchinson, actually I was more willing to build my own CMS. I can write php and some javascrip and my actual website is based on php. Before thinking about Node, I was thinking about Joomla and make my own template and tweaks, but as I went along I noticed the platform could not hold the social part of my website the way I wished...then node appeared but I've only seen awesome APPs build on in, like koding.com or klout.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree that this is rather subjective, but that said having some experience with node I don't know that there is any particular advantage to using it in this instance. I think frameworks like Django (Python) and Rails (Ruby) are more or less built to accomodate this type of use-case and assuming you have PHP experience but not a lot of node experience, would likely be easier for you to build and deploy a working CMS with very quickly.

Based on what you've described I don't know that any of the advantages of using node will be particularly relevant, and it's unlikely that using node instead of any other modern framework and web server will have a huge impact on your site's performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is quite subjective, as the performance of any application written using modern and maintained languages will depend mostly on the skills of the developer(s), and if your website reaches a certain scale it will not depend only on the language but also on the architecture of your distributed system.

Some of the usual strengths of node are that it is event driven, single language for front-end, back-end thus developer integration should be easier. It's event-driven model gives it a nice and easy(subjective!) way to write and understand (for new devs) applications that make heavy use of concurrent operations such as data-intensive operation across distributed systems.